# Are there IF Hidden Statements in VBA for PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

I'm trying to write a macro in PowerPoint that is basically an IF statement. I have 4 boxes, and I have animations that when they are clicked, they fade out.  Is it possible to have a macro that recognizes when all 4 boxes are gone, and then fades in a fifth box?

So 4 boxes disappear upon the users control, then once they are all gone, have a fifth one appear automatically. Is this possible?

Comment: don't know about ppt scripting at all, but most animation handlers have some way of signaling when they're done. count how many "done" notices you receive, and when you hit 4, start the fade on the 5th box.

Comment: you don't have to write macro to do this. there is animation control as standard solution in PP. Why than VBA??

Comment: How do you count the done notices?

Answer (score 0):

No vba needed.  Give the fifth one whatever animation you like, then set it to After Previous.  Add a delay if need be.  It'll animate in after the previous (ie, fourth shape) disappears.

Comment: I tried with the After Previous, but the problem is people randomly choose when the 4 boxes disappear. If the box that triggers the entrance of the fifth box is clicked first, then it will appear regardless of whether or not the other three have been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Ah.  Thanks for clarifying.

Here you go:

```
' Give each of the four shapes an action setting of Run Macro:  HideMe

Sub HideMe(oSh As Shape)
    Dim oSl As Slide

    ' hide the clicked shape
    oSh.Visible = False

    ' test to see if all four shapes are hidden now
    ' edit to reflect the actual names of the shapes in use

    Set oSl = oSh.Parent    ' the slide containing the clicked shape
    With oSl
        If Not .Shapes("Rectangle 3").Visible Then
            If Not .Shapes("Rectangle 4").Visible Then
                If Not .Shapes("Rectangle 5").Visible Then
                    If Not .Shapes("Rectangle 6").Visible Then
                        ' they're all hidden, so make the new shape visible
                        .Shapes("Rectangle 7").Visible = True
                    End If
                End If

            End If
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Sub MakeMeInvisible()
' run this after selecting the final shape
' to make it invisible to begin with
    ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Visible = False
End Sub
```